# Cannot find glyphtounicode.sty

Tags: packages

I am trying to build a resume from this [Github project](https://github.com/sb2nov/resume), however while executing the docker command I am getting this error. Googling suggested to download the sty file from CTAN but I cannot find it, can anyone help me here please?

```
LaTeX Error: File `glyphtounicode.sty' not found.
```

I also tried pasting the .tex file in overleaf and it gave me the same error.

PS: I am running MacOS if it helps.

Comment: Are you writing `\usepackage{glyphtounicode}`? You should use `\input{glyphtounicode}`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [@campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82917/campa) in the comments, using `glyphtounicode` worked like a charm :)